# What does this BatchUpdateException mean?

Tags: java, exception, sqlexception, batch-updates

I'm getting this BatchUpdateException from a stmt.executeBatch() statement:

```
BatchUpdateException: A resultset was created for update
```

The internet does not have any information on this exception message. What does it mean? The traceback doesn't contain anything useful other than that a stored procedure failed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd interpret the message as meaning that an SQL statement that you added via `addBatch()` has produced a `ResultSet`, meaning that it's not your normal `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement.

Statements that should return results can't be executed in batches with JDBC.

The [JDBC Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) (under the heading "Handling Batch Update Exceptions") confirms it:

> You will get a BatchUpdateException when you call the method executeBatch if (1) one of the SQL statements you added to the batch produces a result set (usually a query) or (2) one of the SQL statements in the batch does not execute successfully for some other reason.

You seem to be running into case 1 here.

Answer (score 1):

A batch-update are several insert/update/delete statements which are processed by the database together. This is usualy done for perfomance reasons. 1x 1000 inserts is much faster than 1000x 1 insert. A BatchUpdateException means 1 (or more) statements failed most often due to a constraint-violation.
You will have to look at the stored procedure to see what it has been doing. Mayby your dba can give you more information about what went wrong.

Comment: This is one reason for a `BatchUpdateException`, he seems to be seeing the other one (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I dropped one column from the table.
When i tried to insert records to that table i was getting BatchUpdateException.

After running the below command the problem got solved

REORG TABLE TABLE_NAME

Comment: this does not really asnwers the questions as it was: _"What does BatchUpdateException mean?"_